# Select either Max or Min value from each of combined files in Python

Tags: python, select, max, min

```
# File 1
Column = ['1', '2', '3']

# File 2
Column = ['-2', '-6', '-7', '-6', '-7']

# File 3
Column=['0', '3', '4', '6', '5']

# File 4
Column = ['-1', '-2', '-3', '-3', '-3']

# Combined files
Column = ['1', '2', '3', '-2', '-6', '-7', '-6', '-7', '0', '3', '4', '6', '5', '-1', '-2', '-3', '-3', '-3']
```

Guys, I want to select either max or min value from each file in the combined files.

Expected output:

```
Column = ['3', '-7', '6', '-3']
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for the `abs` maximum value for each column. Try the code below

```py
Column1 = [1, 2, 3]
Column2 = [-2, -6, -7, -6, -7]
Column3 = [0, 3, 4, 6, 5]
Column4 = [-1, -2, -3, -3, -3]

print(max(Column1, key=abs))
print(max(Column2, key=abs))
print(max(Column3, key=abs))
print(max(Column4, key=abs))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Within your lists are strings and not integers so you should first convert them into integers:

--> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-converting-all-strings-in-list-to-integers/

It's the same as asking a person "What's the biggest value of apples, oranges, pears".

After that what you simply do is use the max and min function within python.

```
Column = [1, 2, 3]

print(max(Column))

--> 3

print(min(Column))

--> 1
```

I hope I could help a little bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```py
column=[sorted(column1)[random.randint(-1,0)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these.

This method first sort the lists

```py
column=[]
column.append(sorted(column1)[random.randint(-1,0)])
column.append(sorted(column2)[random.randint(-1,0)])
column.append(sorted(column3)[random.randint(-1,0)])
column.appemd(sorted(column4)[random.randint(-1,0)])
column.append(sorted(column5)[random.randint(-1,0)])
```

Thus use random.choice function

```py
column=[]
column.append(random.choice(max(column1),min(column1)))
column.append(random.choice(max(column2),min(column2)))
column.append(random.choice(max(column3),min(column3)))
column.append(random.choice(max(column4),min(column4)))
column.append(random.choice(max(column5),min(column5)))
```